# Adding Value in a textfield

Tags: javascript, function, textbox

I have one input text where the value is "5+3" I believe this is a plain string, is there anyway to parse it as (8) in a alert() function? 5 + 3 is a value of one textbox and its not separated by another textbox. Is there any javascript function can handle this?

Comment: What other things can the input text contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval()` can execute strings as JavaScript statements:

```
<input type="text" id="addNums" />
var addNumsInput = document.getElementById('addNums'),
    val = addNumsInput.value;

alert(eval(val));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LAwm3/

**Just for your reference**, `eval is evil` https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_nf=1&tok=WiRGhtSngs9KeYHImoAsFQ&cp=6&gs_id=3e&xhr=t&q=eval+is+evil&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=eval+i&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=2aae9199cf6ab275&biw=1920&bih=989

Comment: How about `<input onblur="alert(eval(this.value));">`?

Comment: @RobG - Yes, I just find that using `this` confuses new JS devs =) but a better solution

Comment: There are some things that *eval* is good for, this is one of them. You may want to validate the string is only allowable characters before executing it, unless you intent to provide a console for executing random scripts (which the address bar and various deubuggers provide).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval()`:

```
alert(eval("5+3")); // alerts 8
```

Comment: I think that is exactly what I had written.